# Socket, Read and Write threads

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

Using socket connection i need to have two threads, one for reading and one for writing. I found other questions about socket connections but I don't understand how i can use the same socket in two different threads.

 I have to create a socket in a different thread from the UI thread, so i need to start a thread to create the socket. Where can i start the two threads?

Comment: You can create the socket in one thread and pass it to another, why not? You can as well create thread-derived class instance and pass it everything it needs before actually starting the thread. Where's the problem, exactly?

Comment: The problem is that I need some code, it would be useful an example of how can I use the socket between different threads

Answer (score 2):

Sample code structure to give you an idea.

```
public class SocketActivity extends Activity {
    Socket s;
    OutputStream dout;
    String ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 8080;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    s = new Socket(ip, port);
                    new Thread(new ReaderRunnable(s));
                    new Thread(new WriteRunnable(s));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Handle error state
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // You can put this class outside activity with public scope
    class ReaderRunnable implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;

        public ReaderRunnable(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    //Do reader code
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                //Handle error case
            }
        }
    }

    // You can put this class outside activity with public scope
    class WriteRunnable implements Runnable {
        Socket socket;

        public WriteRunnable(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (socket != null && socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    InputStream out = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    //Do writer code
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                //Handle error case
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question this is client side. You don't have to use the socket itself in two different threads. For the read thread you use the InputStream of the socket, and for the write thread you use the OutputStream. 
That way you don't have to create a seperate thread just for the socket. Both the read and write threads can be started from the UI thread. For creating the threads i refer you to the Android Documentation [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: @jane1012 No, not in the UI thread, otherwise you will block the UI while it is connecting. Start a separate thread to create and connect the socket. That thread can also be the read or the write thread and it can start the other one.

Comment: As @EJP stated, doing I/O from UI thread is just plain wrong. Also, we don't know if one thread is enough - perhaps full-duplex communication (as opposed to request/response in a loop) is required? You just don't know that.

Comment: Thank you for reply.The client has to manage an asynchronous data stream in input and output, the front end could not response in the same order of the request message. That is why I need 2 threads to send and receive messages